# Bundle a React native component only

Tags: javascript, react-native, webpack, ecmascript-6, babeljs

Is there a way to bundle / minify and obfuscate a single React Native component and have it accessible like normal (i.e. `import SomeComponent from 'some-component'`), without including `react-native` and other `node_modules`?

I want to be able to distribute this component over NPM, and have it integrate with other projects that already use react-native.  So in this case, when `some-component` imports say a `View` from `react-native`, I want it to access the main project's `react-native`.

Answer (score 1):

That's what happens anyway.

Since [npm 3.0.0](https://github.com/npm/npm/releases?after=v2.12.1) dependencies are now installed into a flat tree (similar to yarn).

> **Flat, flat, flat!**
>
> Your dependencies will now be installed maximally flat. Insofar as is possible, all of your dependencies, and their dependencies, and THEIR dependencies will be installed in your project's node_modules folder with no nesting. You'll only see modules nested underneath one another when two (or more) modules have conflicting dependencies.

This means that until your dependencies require different versions of `react-native` they'll all use the same copy.

For further control you can lock the package's dependencies versions with [npm-shrinkwrap](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/shrinkwrap).

Comment: I am talking about a single react native component and bundling it only, with obfuscation, and without including other dependencies.  Do you have an example of how to do this?

Comment: You have to include dependencies when you depend on them. Do you have a reason not to?

Comment: By include I mean not have them present in the JS bundle.  I made an edit on the question to hopefully further clarify what I'm getting at...  please reread (I am aware of NPM 3, but my question is covering a different topic.)

Comment: I understand you somewhat better, but still not fully. What do you mean by 'have them present in the JS bundle'? The dependencies are not bundled with your npm module. To use, for example `View` you absolutely have to do `import {View} from 'react-native'`. You should also add `react-native` to your package.json dependencies. The react-native, however, is not bundled in the package. npm will install react-native when installing your package, but only if it was not already installed. Can you maybe explain what exactly are you trying to prevent, so I can better understand you?

Comment: Sure.  So what I'm trying to do is take a component out of an existing RN app, obfuscate it and its us components, but still have it be usable with other react native apps.  The key here is obfuscate -- so it will retain import { View } from "react-native" rather than then it into import J from "01".  I can use react-native bundle CLI to do the latter, but even then it includes all of node_modules in bundle.  Need a way to do the former while retaining clear references to dependencies.

Comment: Why don't you just obfuscate everything but the imports, then? I'm not sure if there is a tool for this, you might have to fix it yourself. Or maybe someone will have a better answer than me. :)

Comment: Yeah, that's the ideal solution, but how is the main question.